# How to convert geographic data to Xarray dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation, python-xarray

I have a relative gravity dataset of 697 measurements taken at points with latitude and longitude. I am having trouble converting to an Xarray dataset so that I can inevitably create an interpolated grid with Xarray.interp_like.

I tried creating the DataArray from a series and from a Dataframe using the following article: https://towardsdatascience.com/basic-data-structures-of-xarray-80bab8094efa

Using the series method:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays=[lat_grav,long_grav],names=["lat","lon"])
s = pd.Series(data=rel_grav,index=idx)
s
lat        lon        
36.713923  -116.120574   NaN
           -116.120574   NaN
           -116.120574   NaN
36.712458  -116.125034   NaN
           -116.125034   NaN
                          ..
36.703896  -116.116244   NaN
           -116.116244   NaN
36.725249  -116.124976   NaN
           -116.124976   NaN
           -116.124976   NaN
```

The relative gravity measurements remain as NaNs so I decided to check with the DataFrame method:

```
rel_grav_df = pd.DataFrame({"relativegrav":rel_grav,"lat":lat_grav,"lon":lon_grav})
rel_grav_df = rel_grav_df.reset_index(drop = True)
rel_grav_df
    relativegrav    lat lon
0   979517.368887   36.713923   -116.120574
1   979517.369767   36.713923   -116.120574
2   979517.370685   36.713923   -116.120574
3   979519.096209   36.712458   -116.125034
```

Trying to pivot the table in the example I use the following code and get the error:

```
df_pv = rel_grav_df.pivot(index="lat",columns="lon")
Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

That's why I originally tried to reset_index but neither method worked. For my final result I would like to interpolate the gravity to the same size as a topography grid I have using the following code:

```
gravity_interp = gravity.interp_like(topography,kwargs={"fill_value":None})
```

Any help would be appreciated!
***Below edited***
I found duplicates in the data so here is the updated dataframe:

```
rel_grav_df = pd.DataFrame({"relativegrav":rel_grav,"lat":lat_grav,"lon":long_grav})

rel_grav_df = rel_grav_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['lat'])
rel_grav_df = rel_grav_df.reset_index(drop = True)
rel_grav_df.to_csv(r'rel_grav_data.txt',sep=' ', mode = 'a')
```

For data that looks like:

```
 relativegrav lat lon
0 979517.3688865899 36.7139233 -116.1205735
1 979519.096208526 36.7124585 -116.1250345
2 979518.8915050578 36.71282822 -116.1316972
3 979531.2591178748 36.70126449 -116.1439218
4 979526.3018131296 36.70558774 -116.1420382
5 979524.8843729249 36.70548686 -116.1359999
6 979521.9290486736 36.70901614 -116.1335681
7 979514.2801810974 36.71966692 -116.1100001
8 979528.4878656694 36.72797377 -116.0854069
9 979521.5282591976 36.72430037 -116.0944469
10 979517.7510474161 36.72091093 -116.1030826
11 979515.6928347832 36.7191884 -116.1074014
12 979516.3006383271 36.71579345 -116.1160991
```

Now creating the DataArray:

```
df_pv = rel_grav_df.pivot(index="lat",columns="lon")
df_pv = df_pv.droplevel(0,axis=1)
da = xr.DataArray(data = df_pv)
da
xarray.DataArraylat: 212lon: 212
array([[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       ...,
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]])
Coordinates:
lat
(lat)
float64
36.69 36.69 36.69 ... 36.76 36.76
lon
(lon)
float64
-116.1 -116.1 ... -116.1 -116.1
```

The gravity values are not populating the DataArray for some reason still.

Comment: your examples don't make sense together. `pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays` should produce a result very similar to `rel_grav_df` if `lat_grav, lon_grav` are the same in both cases. can you provide a full [mre] which can produce the example code when run straight through from scratch? without knowing where these come from it's hard to help.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I've edited the post with more information for an example if that helps!

Comment: are these specific points in space, not on a regular grid? how are you planning to interpolate the data? nearest neighbor? bilinear?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado these measurements were taken on earth's surface at these lat/lon points. I would like to use xarray.Dataset.interp_like to interpolate to the topography grid I am using. The default is linear.

Comment: got it. you can't actually do this. xarray needs *regular grids* - it requires that there is a value for every x/y combination. so you actually need to do this interpolation first, before heading to xarray. I'd set up an interpolator using one of the interpolators in [`scipy.interpolate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) - it sounds like you probably want to do something like a first pass with `LinearNDInterpolator` and then fill gaps and make a second pass with `NearestNDInterpolator`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to deal with duplicates. Otherwise how would you fill your pivot table when lat and lon are the same but rel_grav is different. For example take the mean of all duplicated entries with same lat and lon:

```
import pandas as pd
rel_grav_df = pd.DataFrame([
    [979517.368887,   36.713923,   -116.120574],
    [979517.369767,   36.713923,   -116.120574],
    [979517.370685,   36.713923,   -116.120574],
    [979519.096209,   36.712458,   -116.125034],
],
    columns = ["relativegrav",    "lat", "lon"]
)


rel_grav_df.groupby(["lat", "lon"]).mean().reset_index().pivot(index=["lat"],columns=["lon"])
```

Output:

```
    relativegrav
lon -116.125034 -116.120574
lat     
36.712458   979519.096209   NaN
36.713923   NaN 979517.36978
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an important difference between pointwise data in 2D (what you have), and data on a regular 2D grid. While you can store and work with pointwise data in xarray, xarray's spatial operations will not work the way you're anticipating. Instead, xarray would treat the only indexing dimension, "point", as the sole dimension of the dataset. So your plan as you've outlined it won't work.

Instead, if your goal is to interpolate the data onto a regular 2D grid, you need to do this interpolation yourself, before you get to xarray. For this, [`scipy.interpolate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) is a great place to look. I've implemented a quick nearest neighbor interpolation here - you could do something more complex if you'd like:

```py
In [18]: interpolator = scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator(
    ...:     df[['lon', 'lat']].values, df['relativegrav'].values
    ...: )

In [19]: # define your target grid however you'd like
    ...: y = np.linspace(36.7, 36.73, 100)
    ...: x = np.linspace(-116.2, -116, 200)
    ...: # broadcast these against eachother to get every combo of x, y points
    ...: xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    ...:
    ...: values = interpolator(xx.flat, yy.flat).reshape(xx.shape)

In [20]: filled = xr.DataArray(values, dims=['lat', 'lon'], coords=[y, x])
```

Now you have data on a full 2D regular grid:

```py
In [23]: filled
Out[23]:
<xarray.DataArray (lat: 100, lon: 200)>
array([[979531.25911787, 979531.25911787, 979531.25911787, ...,
        979528.48786567, 979528.48786567, 979528.48786567],
       [979531.25911787, 979531.25911787, 979531.25911787, ...,
        979528.48786567, 979528.48786567, 979528.48786567],
       [979531.25911787, 979531.25911787, 979531.25911787, ...,
        979528.48786567, 979528.48786567, 979528.48786567],
       ...,
       [979526.30181313, 979526.30181313, 979526.30181313, ...,
        979528.48786567, 979528.48786567, 979528.48786567],
       [979526.30181313, 979526.30181313, 979526.30181313, ...,
        979528.48786567, 979528.48786567, 979528.48786567],
       [979526.30181313, 979526.30181313, 979526.30181313, ...,
        979528.48786567, 979528.48786567, 979528.48786567]])
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 36.7 36.7 36.7 36.7 36.7 ... 36.73 36.73 36.73 36.73
  * lon      (lon) float64 -116.2 -116.2 -116.2 -116.2 ... -116.0 -116.0 -116.0
```

Comment: Thank you @MichaelDelgado I tried your example. However, the values of my array are the same number and I tried `filled.plot.imshow(x = 'lon',y='lat')` which shows only 1 color value. The interpolation worked but I'm not sure why I only have 1 repeated value as the DataArray.

Comment: your data values are all really similar. is it possible you just can't see the variation? could you plot `(filled - filled.mean())` to see if it's just a scaling problem? also, you will only get one value if the grid you define is not interior to your points, e.g. if you mixed up lat and lon or something. so if you truly only have one value, make sure you're not just interpolating one edge point to all values. but without having a full [mre] it's hard to understand what's going wrong with your issue.